# Show dates between chosen dateA and dateB via JAVA JSP

Tags: java, jsp, date

I want to show the dates between DateA and DateB in a jsp table

**For example:**

DateA = 23-01-2014
DateB = 26-01-2014

**Output:**

Dates

- 23-01-2014
- 24-01-2014
- 25-01-2014
- 26-01-2014

So far I've done this:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="datepickeer" action="showdates.jsp" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>Date début :</td> <td><input type = "date" name = "dateA">
</td><tr>
<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**showDates.jsp**

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.Date,java.text.SimpleDateFormat,java.text.ParseException"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String dateStr = request.getParameter("dateA");
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date result = formater.parse(dateStr);
SimpleDateFormat newFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
out.println(newFormater.format(result));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output when i choose the second of april 2014 is :**

02-04-2014

After creating the **DateA** I should do the same for **DateB** ,then,**what should I do next??**

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Calendar and add 1 to Calendar.Day until your date is reached in a loop

```
    String dateA = "2014-02-02";
    String dateB = "2014-02-06";

    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dateStart = null;
    Date dateEnd = null;

    dateStart = formater.parse(dateA);
    dateEnd = formater.parse(dateB);

    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    c.setTime(dateStart);

    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

    while (!c.getTime().after(dateEnd)) {
        dates.add(c.getTime());
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    for (Date element: dates)
    {
        System.out.println("The date is "  + element);

    }
```

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Comment: sure.. I will edit my response

Comment: thaanks for ur help but your solution didnt work for me  it shows this error : HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: it makes no sense since I'm not referencing Jasper in my code... I tested my code and it works

Comment: hi pat , it worked, when i choose for dateA : 2014/04/03 and for dateB: 2014/04/03 the output is : The date is Thu Apr 03 00:00:00 WAT 2014 The date is Fri Apr 04 00:00:00 WAT 2014 The date is Sat Apr 05 00:00:00 WAT 2014 The date is Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 WAT 2014 , I want the input to look like this: 03-04-2014 04-04-2014 05-04-2014 06-04-2014 ,please help me

Comment: Use a simpleDateFormat... new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")